# jquery if else statements

Tags: jquery, ajax

I was just wondering how to use the function :not in my situation.

This is jquery. I'm trying to select the elements in the list that are not in the condition mention in the if loop.

Json object received: ["blue", "teleport", "love", "transformers", "blink182", "leap year", "database", "valentines", "bearish", "sting", "a1", "telegraph", "trion", "spa", "property", "jolie", "grace", "santa claus"]

I just want to receive the words without the special characters

```
function refreshKeywords(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var refresh_form = jQuery(e.target);
    alert("HELLO");
    $.ajax({
        url: refresh_form.attr('action'),
        type: refresh_form.attr('method'),
        data: refresh_form.serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response) {
            var list = response.new_list;
            if (list != "["
            or list != "]"
            or list != "{"
            or list != "}"
            $('#keywords').append("<li>" + list + "</li>");
            },
        });
    }​
```

Would appreciate if anyone know how to input the :not function into my code. Thank you so much.

Comment: What you have is not valid JavaScript.  What are you trying use the `:not` "function" for?

Comment: ":not" is a selector filter and has nothing to do with strings. Hard to figure out what you are trying to parse..post a little of the json

Comment: edited. Sorry for not being clear earlier on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The json response is not a human readable string the way you are approaching it. It is an array that you need to loop over to parse vales

```
success: function(response) {
    var html='';
    $.each(response, function( i, item){
       html+= "<li>" + item + "</li>";
    });
    $('#keywords').append(html)

 },
```

Answer (score 1):

There would be no use for the :not selector here. The :not selector is meant for DOM elements.

http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/

Answer (score 1):

`:not` is a filter, it is used to filter elements out of a selection, e.g:

```
$("input:not([type='submit'])")
```

This would select all `input` elements on the page, except those with a type attribute equal to `submit`

It is advised to use the `not()` method for readability instead of the `:not` filter

What is it you're trying to do and what is not working?

So looking at your updates, you cannot use the word 'or' in the if conditional, use the double-pipe || instead, e.g.

```
if (list != "[" || list != "]" || list != "{" || list != "}") {
    $('#keywords').append("<li>" + list + "</li>");
}
```

Except, you probably want to use && instead, because you don't want any of those characters:

```
if (list != "[" && list != "]" && list != "{" && list != "}") {
        $('#keywords').append("<li>" + list + "</li>");
    }
```

But...you probably want to do it a different way in any case, instead of working directly with the JSON string, you might want to parse it to turn it into an actual JavaScript object so that you can work with it easier, e.g.

```
var array = $.parseJSON(response.new_list);
```

Comment: edited my question above. Trying to use a if else loop in jquery itself.

Comment: :not is actually a selector, not a filter, for it selects elements rather than filters them.

Comment: So it selects things by not selecting them? ;)

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a [JSON parser](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js). Parse then iterate over the resultant array.

```
//Cache #keywords outside the loop to make it faster.
var array = JSON.parse(response.new_list), keywords = $("#keywords");
for(var i = 0, len = array.length; i<len; i++) {
    keywords.append("<li>" + array[i] + "</li>");
}
```

Comment: for some reason for loops always make my code not functionable. Any ideas why?

Comment: no need to use JSON.parse within a jQuery ajax response, will be handled by core